# redux saga notifications react native

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I'm having a hard time trying to activate my react native switch, getting the app notification.

the user must activate the option to receive notification from the application on the device.

this procedure has already been performed, the second step is

I have a react native switch

```js
{
   name: 'storeNotificationSetting',
   params: ['notification'],
   function: (state, action) => {
     return {...state, notification: action.notification};
   },
},
```

```js
  saveSwitchChange = isTouchIdEnabled => {
    this.props.storeNotificationSetting(isTouchIdEnabled);
  };
```

```js
<Switch
   label='Ativar Notificações'
   name='isNotificationsEnabled'
   onChange={this.saveSwitchChange}
/>
```

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { notification } = state.global;
  return {
    notification,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const { storeNotificationSetting } = globalActionCreators;
  return {
    storeNotificationSetting: function (isTouchIdEnabled) {
      return dispatch(storeNotificationSetting(isTouchIdEnabled));
    },
  };
}
```

How can I make my saga take the mobile device feature and activate my switch so that this notification functionality is activated?

Comment: you can communicate between a saga and a UI component via the redux store.
If you need a switch to have specific value, the process can be:
1. have the saga populate the redux store
2. have the switch take its state from the store
. redux-saga is less concerned with the state of presentation. Most of the time you won't change a UI component directly from a redux-saga but use the store as the source of truth.

Comment: That's the problem, I still haven't found a way to do this.